# Python: Extract different tables and merge them into a single CSV file

Tags: python, pandas, csv, beautifulsoup

I want to find all the cold-storages in India and their capacity. The information is available in https://www.napanta.com/cold-storage/

Every state has its URL (example: https://www.napanta.com/cold-storage/andhra-pradesh/) ... and going to every state URL, we see that it has many districts, and each district has its own URL (https://www.napanta.com/cold-storage/andhra-pradesh/krishna) for the Krishna district in A.P.

My objective is to create One Single CSV files that have this information from all districts of every state. Additional columns in this One Big CSV file will be State and District name.

After we have this one state-district data frame, I want to append it to the larger dataframe for all states and districts. Finally export this large master dataframe into a single CSV file. The final result should be a single CSV file that contains all the data of every district of every state.

I tried the **scraping** part with Beautiful Soup and now, I'm stuck. Please, help me with the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should get list of all links first. Can be done with selenium and beautiful-soup. Then you could try to loop over list of those links and read tables with pandas:

```py
import pandas as pd
li = []
for link in list_of_links:
    dfi = pd.read_html(link)
    li.append(dfi)
df = pd.concat(li)
df.to_csv("Your_File.csv")
```

Comment: Since I'm new to Python, can you give some more insights in terms of Python?

Comment: How to get the list of all links? Do I have to copy-paste all links manually or is there some Python code?

Answer (score 1):

Once you have all the information, you can load it to a data frame and transform it using pandas, then export it to a csv using

```
DataFrame.to_csv('filename.csv')
```

Comment: Can you help me from the beginning like how to save and then merge different CSV files into a single file?

Comment: You can load the files with 

`df1 = pandas.read_csv('filename1')`
`df2 = pandas.read_csv('filename2')`

After that you can concatenate them using `df = df1 + df2` then output the dataframe using `df.to_csv('output_file.csv')`